# Difference between symmetric crypto algorithms

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

C# looks to have 4 different symmetric crypto algorithms: RijndaelManaged, DESCryptoServiceProvider, RC2CryptoServiceProvider, and TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.

I am looking for more information between them. Mainly what is the differences between each of them. MSDN isn't being much help, or I am just tired. ;) I am sure there is pro and cons between each of them, just like anything where there are multiple ways of doing something.

Thank you for any enlightenment. 

Tony

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This the Ranking (for year 2015) the strongest algorithm appears on top:

- Rijndael (more commonly referred to as [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard))
- [Triple DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES)
- [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)
- [RC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2)

Use AES.

In more details:

- DES is the old "data encryption standard" from the seventies. Its key size is too short for proper security (56 effective bits; this can be brute-forced, as has been demonstrated [more than ten years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)). Also, DES uses 64-bit blocks, which raises some potential issues when encrypting several gigabytes of data with the same key (a gigabyte is not that big nowadays).
- 3DES is a trick to reuse DES implementations, by cascading three instances of DES (with distinct keys). 3DES is believed to be secure up to at least "*2<sup>112</sup>*" security (which is quite a lot, and quite far in the realm of "not breakable with today's technology"). But it is slow, especially in software (DES was designed for efficient hardware implementation, but it sucks in software; and 3DES sucks three times as much).
- AES is the successor of DES as standard symmetric encryption algorithm for US federal organizations (and as standard for pretty much everybody else, too). AES accepts keys of 128, 192 or 256 bits (128 bits is already very unbreakable), uses 128-bit blocks (so no issue there), and is efficient in both software and hardware. It was selected through an open competition involving hundreds of cryptographers during several years. Basically, you cannot have better than that.

So, when in doubt, use AES.

Note that a block cipher is a box which encrypts "blocks" (128-bit chunks of data with AES). When encrypting a "message" which may be longer than 128 bits, the message must be split into blocks, and the actual way you do the split is called the [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2) or "chaining". The naive mode (simple split) is called ECB and has issues. Using a block cipher properly is not easy, and it is more important than selecting between, e.g., AES or 3DES.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

Answer (score 16):

Short answer: ***use Rijndael***.

What the various options are:

[RC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2) is a weak, broken cipher built in the late 80s for export, because at the time American companies were restricted from exporting 'strong' encryption.  It has a key length of 40 bits, which makes brute forcing it on today's hardware trivial (it is, after all, 20 years later).

It's name stands for Rivest Cipher No. 2, after it's creator Ron Rivest (a world-renown crpytographer, the 'R' in RSA).

[DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) was the Data Encryption Standard, and was termed strong crpytography.  With a key length of 56 bits, however, it is now [within range of brute-force decryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DESCHALL_Project).

[3DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3des) is running DES three times.  Just running DES twice doesn't make it much stronger, actually, but the third time does.  It is effectively 116 bit encrpytion (with a 196-bit key).

3DES is a very good, strong encrpytion by today's standard.

So RC2, DES and 3DES are in the cipher suite to provide compatibility with business systems that use those ciphers.

Rijndael is however the modern cipher of choice.  It is the official replacement for DES, termed the [Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

It comes in a range of keysizes, but it is [important](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html) to ***use 128-bit***.  Only use other key lengths (including the longest, 256-bit) for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Why should we only use 128bit unless for compatibility reasons?

Comment: The 'important' link talks about attacks against the longer 256-bit.

Comment: yet proving that while I can see, I am still blind. :) Thanks.

Comment: @Will, you should read the linked page again. The attack is practical (with a really wide definition of practical) only for Rijndael-192 and Rijndael-256 with fewer rounds than AES requires. Since you should be following AES, the attack is completely impractical against standard AES implementations.

Comment: -1 for giving false impression that AES-192/256 are considered insecure...

Comment: @BlueRaja, @iconiK, If you read the link, Bruce makes clear recommendations: "And for new applications I suggest that people don't use AES-256. AES-128 provides more than enough security margin for the forseeable future. But if you're already using AES-256, there's no reason to change."  So clearly it ***is*** important to point out to people that they should use 128-bit on new projects, and not adopt a longer key-length.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed As Stated DES is not very strong. Triple DES is strong (there haven't AFAIK been any proper attacks against it) but it is somewhat slower.

Rijndael is the same as AES (Advanced Encryption Standard - approved by NSA, very strong) but with more choice about the size of your key.

Unfortunately I also know little about RC2. Unless it is significantly faster that Rijndael I wouldn't see much reason not to go for Rijndael (and even then I'd want to look at how secure it was.)

The following is speculation... RC2 is an ancestor by a few generations of RC6, which was one of the finalists for the selection of a cipher to be named as AES. Rijndael was chosen over RC6 so one would assume that Rijndael is better by several degrees than RC2.

Comment: If you're comparing 3DES to Rijndael. It is not slower. We ran a test encrypting approx. 8000 strings and 3DES was around 2 seconds as opposed to 18 seconds with Rijndael.

Comment: Are you sure your 3DES wan't being handled by a hardware accelerator?

Comment: This was done within a WPF application.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with [RijndaelManaged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or TripleDES as those are stronger than DES.

The main weakness in DES is its [shorter keylength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) which could allow possible brute force attacks. Doing an encryption using DES three times is a possible means of strengthening your final result, hence TripleDES. I don't know much about RC2, so I can't comment on that method.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a really good reason not to, just use RijndaelManaged.  Rijndael is what became AES, the general replacement to DES, so it's definitely preferred over DES and TripleDES unless you need to be compatible with some old DES-based system.  There's nothing particularly wrong with RC2, but it's older than AES and there's no real reason to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Rijndael is the best.

DES is not very good, pretty easy to crack with enough horsepower.
Triple DES is a bit better than DES (its just DES repeated 3 times).

If you're interested, look into the bouncy castle crypto library for more c# crypto goodness:
http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Comment: 3DES is substantially more secure than DES - DES is within the bounds of today's computer power, 3DES remains beyond bruteforceable.  NIST consider it secure from brute force up until 2030.

DES is 56bit, 3DES is 112bit.

Comment: or [168 bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DES#Keying_options)

Answer (score 0):

These algorithms represent various points on the speed vs. strength trade-off curve.

(weakest/fastest) RC2 < DES < 3DES < AES/Rijndael (strongest/slowest)

I'm not familiar with the API though, is there any additional difference between the 'Managed' and 'CryptoServiceProvider' classes?

Comment: -1, AES is significantly faster than DES/3DES.  That was the whole purpose of the AES contest to begin with...