# Encrypt in VB.NET and Decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, tripledes

I am trying to write a function in PHP and in VB.NET that uses [Triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) to pass in BOTH directions encrypted data. The problem, is that when I try to decrypt a string encrypted in VB.NET using PHP, I get an error message saying that the block size of the IV must match.

The class I wrote in VB.NET, is as follows and is fully functional as it will encrypt and decrypt its own blocks flawlessly.

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography

    Public Class Cipher

        Dim method As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
        Dim key As Byte()

        Public Property Password() As String
            Get
                Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Key)
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                key = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Function Encrypt(data As String) As String
            Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream

            ' Create the encoder to write to the stream.
            Dim dataBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data)
            Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, method.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

            ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
            encStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length)
            encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

            ' IV and Ciphered string are each Base64'd and seperated by a comma, then the whole result is Base64'd
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(method.IV) & "," & Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)))
        End Function

        Public Function Decrypt(data As String) As String
            ' Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array.

            Dim partDecoded As String = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(data))
            Dim dataBytes() As Byte

            If InStr(partDecoded, ",") > 0 Then

                Dim parts() As String = Split(partDecoded, ",")

                ' Get IV from first part
                method.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(parts(0))

                ' Get ciphered data from second part
                dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(parts(1))

                ' Create the stream.
                Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
                ' Create the decoder to write to the stream.
                Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms, method.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

                ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
                decStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length)
                decStream.FlushFinalBlock()

                ' Convert the plaintext stream to a string.
                Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)
            Else
                Return False
            End If

        End Function

        Public Sub New()
            method = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
            method.Mode = CipherMode.CFB
            method.GenerateIV()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Example usage of the above class

```
    Dim c As New Cipher
    c.Password = "12345"

    Dim encrypted As String = c.Encrypt("hello")
    Debug.Print(encrypted)

    Dim decrypted As String = c.Decrypt(encrypted)
    Debug.Print(decrypted)
```

Now I also have the following PHP code which ALSO works (by itself)

```
    class Cipher {
        private $iv;
        private $securekey;

        function __construct($key) {
            $this->securekey = $key;
        }

        function encrypt($string) {
            $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB),MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
            $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $this->securekey, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $this->iv));
            return base64_encode(base64_encode($this->iv) . ',' . $encrypted);
        }

        function decrypt($string) {
            $decrypt = base64_decode($string);
            if(strpos($decrypt,',') > 0) {
                $decrypt = explode(',', $decrypt);
                $this->iv = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
                return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $this->securekey, base64_decode($decrypt[1]), MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $this->iv));
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

PHP Example Usage

```
    $c = new Cipher("12345");
    $encrypted = $c->encrypt("hello");
    echo 'Encrypted: ' . $encrypted . '<br />';

    $decrypted = $c->decrypt($encrypted);
    echo 'Decrypted: ' . $decrypted . '<br />';

    $vb = "MwBOAEoAOQBjAEgAcQAyAC8ASABzAD0ALABmAEUAOQBaAHYAVwBzAFUAYQB3AFYARwBGAHUANABLAGUAVgB3AFcAaABRAD0APQA=";
    echo 'VB.NET Dec: ' . $c->decrypt($vb);
```

What I have included above in the PHP usage, is the [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string made with VB.NET that decodes PERFECTLY in VB.NET as the variable $vb.

This is driving me absolutely batty, as the code is correct, and functional -- in both cases -- so what am I missing and can you point out / fix the problem. I do not wish to use [Rijndael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), or explore other cipher methods, as this one is well established that works across multiple devices natively (iOS, Android, Windows, Linux, etc.).

Comment: why not rijandel ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2175331/3802940

Comment: slow, and not 100% across all platforms.  there are also things in that article which are simply untrue such as a reduced bit encryption due to 3 passes of DES ? ....  the algorythm itself is a bit more complex than 3 passes of the same mechanic.  regardless,  tripledes is defacto -- rijandel, is not.  Replacing this with Rijandel may solve one problem, but create a dozen others.  I need a solution to this problem at hand ... TripleDES.  Why it works perfect in both cases, but, even though they claim to follow RFC -- not each other.  One is not following, and i bet it's PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since no one was able to provide a fully functional BI-DIRECTIONAL solution, I have taken the liberty to provide one for the community on this article.

The problem, is that PHP does not conform to the standards by forcing the strings to be padded in order to match. Presently, there is no known way to reliably pass the IV if randomly generated between .NET and PHP (if you do discover how, or this changes, please feel free to revise this).

Following is the COMPLETE solution for encrypting data using Triple DES in a manner that is compatible with .NET and PHP which allows for bi-directional Triple DES encrypted communication. This method is also compatible with Java, Delphi, Objective-C, and many other languages, however such code is not going to be supplied here as that is not a solution to the posted question.

---

### VB.NET Triple DES Class

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography

    Public Class TripleDES

        Private bPassword As Byte()
        Private sPassword As String

        Public Sub New(Optional ByVal Password As String = "password")
            ' On Class Begin
            Me.Password = Password
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property PasswordHash As String
            Get
                Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
                Return UTF8.GetString(bPassword)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Property Password() As String
            Get
                Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
                Return sPassword
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
                Dim HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
                bPassword = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(value))
                sPassword = value
            End Set
        End Property

    #Region "Encrypt"

        ' Encrypt using Password from Property Set (pre-hashed)
        Public Function Encrypt(ByVal Message As String) As String
            Dim Results() As Byte
            Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
            Using HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
                Dim TDESKey() As Byte = bPassword
                Using TDESAlgorithm As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() With {.Key = TDESKey, .Mode = CipherMode.ECB, .Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7}
                    Dim DataToEncrypt() As Byte = UTF8.GetBytes(Message)
                    Try
                        Dim Encryptor As ICryptoTransform = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor
                        Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length)
                    Finally
                        TDESAlgorithm.Clear()
                        HashProvider.Clear()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(Results)
        End Function

        ' Encrypt using Password as byte array
        Private Function Encrypt(ByVal Message As String, ByVal Password() As Byte) As String
            Dim Results() As Byte
            Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
            Using HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
                Dim TDESKey() As Byte = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(UTF8.GetString(Password)))
                Using TDESAlgorithm As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() With {.Key = TDESKey, .Mode = CipherMode.ECB, .Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7}
                    Dim DataToEncrypt() As Byte = UTF8.GetBytes(Message)
                    Try
                        Dim Encryptor As ICryptoTransform = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor
                        Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length)
                    Finally
                        TDESAlgorithm.Clear()
                        HashProvider.Clear()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(Results)
        End Function

        ' Encrypt using Password as string
        Public Function Encrypt(ByVal Message As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
            Dim Results() As Byte
            Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
            ' Step 1. We hash the Passphrase using MD5
            ' We use the MD5 hash generator as the result is a 128 bit byte array
            ' which is a valid length for the Triple DES encoder we use below
            Using HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
                Dim TDESKey() As Byte = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Password))

                ' Step 2. Create a new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object

                ' Step 3. Setup the encoder
                Using TDESAlgorithm As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() With {.Key = TDESKey, .Mode = CipherMode.ECB, .Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7}
                    ' Step 4. Convert the input string to a byte[]

                    Dim DataToEncrypt() As Byte = UTF8.GetBytes(Message)

                    ' Step 5. Attempt to encrypt the string
                    Try
                        Dim Encryptor As ICryptoTransform = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor
                        Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length)
                    Finally
                        ' Clear the Triple Des and Hashprovider services of any sensitive information
                        TDESAlgorithm.Clear()
                        HashProvider.Clear()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using

            ' Step 6. Return the encrypted string as a base64 encoded string
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(Results)
        End Function
    #End Region

    #Region "Decrypt"
        ' Decrypt using Password from Property (pre-hashed)
        Public Function Decrypt(ByVal Message As String) As String
            Dim Results() As Byte
            Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
            Using HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
                Dim TDESKey() As Byte = Me.bPassword
                Using TDESAlgorithm As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() With {.Key = TDESKey, .Mode = CipherMode.ECB, .Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7}
                    Dim DataToDecrypt() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(Message)
                    Try
                        Dim Decryptor As ICryptoTransform = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor
                        Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length)
                    Finally
                        TDESAlgorithm.Clear()
                        HashProvider.Clear()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
            Return UTF8.GetString(Results)
        End Function

        ' Decrypt using Password as Byte array
        Public Function Decrypt(ByVal Message As String, ByVal Password() As Byte) As String
            Dim Results() As Byte
            Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
            Using HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
                Dim TDESKey() As Byte = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(UTF8.GetString(Password)))
                Using TDESAlgorithm As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() With {.Key = TDESKey, .Mode = CipherMode.ECB, .Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7}
                    Dim DataToDecrypt() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(Message)
                    Try
                        Dim Decryptor As ICryptoTransform = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor
                        Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length)
                    Finally
                        TDESAlgorithm.Clear()
                        HashProvider.Clear()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
            Return UTF8.GetString(Results)
        End Function


        ' Decrypt using Password as string
        Public Function Decrypt(ByVal Message As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
            Dim Results() As Byte
            Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding

            ' Step 1. We hash the pass phrase using MD5
            ' We use the MD5 hash generator as the result is a 128-bit byte array
            ' which is a valid length for the Triple DES encoder we use below
            Using HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
                Dim TDESKey() As Byte = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Password))

                ' Step 2. Create a new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object
                ' Step 3. Setup the decoder
                Using TDESAlgorithm As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() With {.Key = TDESKey, .Mode = CipherMode.ECB, .Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7}

                    ' Step 4. Convert the input string to a byte[]
                    Dim DataToDecrypt() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(Message)
                    ' Step 5. Attempt to decrypt the string
                    Try
                        Dim Decryptor As ICryptoTransform = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor
                        Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length)
                    Finally

                        ' Clear the Triple Des and Hash provider services of any sensitive information
                        TDESAlgorithm.Clear()
                        HashProvider.Clear()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using

            ' Step 6. Return the decrypted string in UTF8 format
            Return UTF8.GetString(Results)
        End Function

    #End Region

    End Class
```

---

### VB.NET Triple DES Class Usage

```
    Dim tdes As New TripleDES("12345")
    Dim vbEncrypted = tdes.Encrypt("Encrypted using VB.NET")
    Dim phpEncrypted = "5Ittyr0+jiI7QQmPrvSVnMc9MEWQCjAN"

    Debug.Print("PHP Encrypted: " & phpEncrypted)
    Debug.Print("VB Encrypted: " & vbEncrypted)
    Debug.Print("PHP Encrypted (decrypted result): " & tdes.Decrypt(phpEncrypted))
    Debug.Print("VB Encrypted (decrypted result): " & tdes.Decrypt(vbEncrypted))
```

---

### PHP Triple DES Class

```
    class TripleDES {
        private $bPassword;
        private $sPassword;

        function __construct($Password) {
            $this->bPassword  = md5(utf8_encode($Password),TRUE);
            $this->bPassword .= substr($this->bPassword,0,8);
            $this->sPassword - $Password;
        }

        function Password($Password = "") {
            if($Password == "") {
                return $this->sPassword;
            } else {
                $this->bPassword  = md5(utf8_encode($Password),TRUE);
                $this->bPassword .= substr($this->bPassword,0,8);
                $this->sPassword - $Password;
            }
        }

        function PasswordHash() {
            return $this->bPassword;
        }

        function Encrypt($Message, $Password = "") {
            if($Password <> "") { $this->Password($Password); }
            $size=mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes','ecb');
            $padding=$size-((strlen($Message)) % $size);
            $Message .= str_repeat(chr($padding),$padding);
            $encrypt  = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes',$this->bPassword,$Message,'ecb');
            return base64_encode($encrypt);
        }

        function Decrypt($message, $Password = "") {
            if($Password <> "") { $this->Password($Password); }
            return trim(mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $this->bPassword, base64_decode($message), 'ecb'), ord(2));
        }

    }
```

---

### PHP Triple DES Class Usage

```
    $tdes = new TripleDES("12345");

    $phpEncrypted = $tdes->encrypt("Encrypted using PHP");
    $vbEncrypted = "5Ittyr0+jiI7QQmPrvSVnP3s2CeoTJmF"; // Encrypted using VB.NET

    echo "PHP Encrypted: " . $phpEncrypted . '<br />';
    echo "VB Encrypted: " . $vbEncrypted . '<br />';
    echo "PHP Encrypted (decrypted result): " . $tdes->Decrypt($phpEncrypted) . '<br />';
    echo "VB Encrypted (decrypted result): " . $tdes->Decrypt($vbEncrypted) . '<br />';
```

I did what I could to make both classes usability level identical as the languages would allow naturally. Since PHP does not allow overloading functions, I had to use the password as an optional parameter, which is a string value. The VB.NET solution has an additional override that allows you to pass the byte value of the password string on encrypt/decrypt functions. The example code provided to show the usage for each, shows the most simplistic form of instantiating the object which both classes allow for setting the password on object creation.

For anyone else out there that was bashing their brains trying to find a WORKING bi-directional solution for Triple DES (and did not want to be forced into the box that everyone seems to be pointing to  -- [Rijndael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)), then this solution is for you, and you can stop banging your head against the wall.

*Added a C# translation of the VB.NET TripleDES class*

### C# Class ( *Added [2017-01-11]* )

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class TripleDES {

    private byte[] bPassword;

    private string sPassword;
    public TripleDES( string Password = "password" ) {
        // On Class Begin
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public string PasswordHash {
        get {
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            return UTF8.GetString( bPassword );
        }
    }

    public string Password {
        get {
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            return sPassword;
        }
        set {
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            bPassword = HashProvider.ComputeHash( UTF8.GetBytes( value ) );
            sPassword = value;
        }
    }

    #region "Encrypt"

    // Encrypt using Password from Property Set (pre-hashed)
    public string Encrypt( string Message ) {
        byte[] Results = null;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        using ( MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider() ) {
            byte[] TDESKey = bPassword;
            using ( TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider { Key = TDESKey, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 } ) {
                byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes( Message );
                try {
                    ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
                    Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock( DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length );
                } finally {
                    TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                    HashProvider.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String( Results );
    }

    // Encrypt using Password as byte array
    private string Encrypt( string Message, byte[] Password ) {
        byte[] Results = null;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        using ( MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider() ) {
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash( UTF8.GetBytes( UTF8.GetString( Password ) ) );
            using ( TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider { Key = TDESKey, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 } ) {
                byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes( Message );
                try {
                    ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
                    Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock( DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length );
                } finally {
                    TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                    HashProvider.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String( Results );
    }

    // Encrypt using Password as string
    public string Encrypt( string Message, string Password ) {
        byte[] Results = null;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        // Step 1. We hash the Passphrase using MD5
        // We use the MD5 hash generator as the result is a 128 bit byte array
        // which is a valid length for the Triple DES encoder we use below
        using ( MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider() ) {
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash( UTF8.GetBytes( Password ) );

            // Step 2. Create a new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object

            // Step 3. Setup the encoder
            using ( TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider { Key = TDESKey, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 } ) {
                // Step 4. Convert the input string to a byte[]

                byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes( Message );

                // Step 5. Attempt to encrypt the string
                try {
                    ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
                    Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock( DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length );
                } finally {
                    // Clear the Triple Des and Hashprovider services of any sensitive information
                    TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                    HashProvider.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        // Step 6. Return the encrypted string as a base64 encoded string
        return Convert.ToBase64String( Results );
    }
    #endregion

    #region "Decrypt"
    // Decrypt using Password from Property (pre-hashed)
    public string Decrypt( string Message ) {
        byte[] Results = null;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        using ( MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider() ) {
            byte[] TDESKey = this.bPassword;
            using ( TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider { Key = TDESKey, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 } ) {
                byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String( Message );
                try {
                    ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
                    Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock( DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length );
                } finally {
                    TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                    HashProvider.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        return UTF8.GetString( Results );
    }

    // Decrypt using Password as Byte array
    public string Decrypt( string Message, byte[] Password ) {
        byte[] Results = null;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        using ( MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider() ) {
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash( UTF8.GetBytes( UTF8.GetString( Password ) ) );
            using ( TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider { Key = TDESKey, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 } ) {
                byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String( Message );
                try {
                    ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
                    Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock( DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length );
                } finally {
                    TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                    HashProvider.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        return UTF8.GetString( Results );
    }


    // Decrypt using Password as string
    public string Decrypt( string Message, string Password ) {
        byte[] Results = null;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

        // Step 1. We hash the pass phrase using MD5
        // We use the MD5 hash generator as the result is a 128-bit byte array
        // which is a valid length for the Triple DES encoder we use below
        using ( MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider() ) {
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash( UTF8.GetBytes( Password ) );

            // Step 2. Create a new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object
            // Step 3. Setup the decoder
            using ( TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider { Key = TDESKey, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 } ) {

                // Step 4. Convert the input string to a byte[]
                byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String( Message );
                // Step 5. Attempt to decrypt the string
                try {
                    ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
                    Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock( DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length );

                } finally {
                    // Clear the Triple Des and Hash provider services of any sensitive information
                    TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                    HashProvider.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        // Step 6. Return the decrypted string in UTF8 format
        return UTF8.GetString( Results );
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Useful and working. However, `mcrypt` is going to removed from PHP in the future (already in next series of releases i.e. 7.2), how to do the decryption using `openssl_decrypt` method instead?

Comment: @W.M. Given that 7.x is slow to phase in due to the number of applications it breaks, it will take some time for the community to catch up (cPanel, IonCube, and so on).   I am looking into a more robust method for ciphering data in transit as I am not fond of 3des (was good years ago). Arguably, 3des is better than no ciphering of raw data.  Need to keep in mind processing (client/server), and quality.  Openssl's methods (in php) are a little slower at the moment. Problem is that this method is the only one (it seems) that works on ios, droid, .net, php .. natively (no 3rd party crap)

Comment: contd --  ... that are understandable across each platform.  Can encrypt *A* on .net as *B* and decrypt *B* on ios/droid/php to get *A* again.  Most methods seem to have some quirks in translation when crossing language boundaries (which in my opinion should not be the case as the math and protocol set as a standard for those ciphers is what should have been followed, and if it was on each, then they should be able to translate [decipher] whatever the others cipher)

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into this since I simply don't want my application to be non functional due to removal of `mcrypt` from `PHP` in the future. Must admit, seems complicated this issue of cross programming language encryption/decryption.

Comment: @W.M. - I have a method somewhat working using certificates for encrypting data from the server using a private key and decrypting on client side using public key. [on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151376/public-key-chunked-encryption-with-c-method-to-decrypt) .  See the adjustments in the solution to improve performance.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: @KraangPrime I was searching for something like this as Im a very beginner , while I was testing your code ( encrypted in VB.NET and decrypted in PHP) I was getting two extra empty space at the end of the decrypted string (https://pastebin.com/BEZRusfW)

Comment: @Hayat - I have updated the PHP code to account for this. Not sure what is causing it, but those blanks were actually the control character STX ( char #2 ).  Added a trim to the method to strip them from the decrypt result.

Comment: Solution for php 7+ in my answer

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 7+ mccrypt wont work, so here the solution for encrypt and decrypt using the library [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib):

```
 $des = new \phpseclib\Crypt\TripleDES(\phpseclib\Crypt\TripleDES::MODE_ECB);
 $key = YOURKEY;
 $p  = md5(utf8_encode($key),TRUE);
 $p .= substr($p,0,8);
 $p - $key;
 $des->setKey($p);

 $phpEncrypted = $des->encrypt("Encrypted using PHP");
 $vbEncrypted = "5Ittyr0+jiI7QQmPrvSVnP3s2CeoTJmF"; // Encrypted using VB.NET

 echo "PHP Encrypted: " . $phpEncrypted . '<br />';
 echo "VB Encrypted: " . $vbEncrypted . '<br />';
 echo "PHP Encrypted (decrypted result): " . $des->decrypt(base64_decode($phpEncrypted)) . '<br />';
 echo "VB Encrypted (decrypted result): " . $des->decrypt(base64_decode($vbEncrypted)) . '<br />';
```

Comment: mcrypt is available for php7 but needs to be installed.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/36402750/3504007