# php 7 Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, php-7

hello guys l have installed php7 from this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7) 
and this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04) too.

but when i try to run a Laravel based project there is an error coming up as follows

> Mcrypt PHP extension required.

I tried to locate mcrypt.so and change the path in mycrpt.ini but i still get the same error i only get this error i Laravel projects

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: I'd recommend doing `composer require phpseclib/mcrypt_compat`. That'll install a pure-PHP mcrypt shim that'll eliminate the need for the mcrypt extension.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Had the same issue - PHP7 missing mcrypt.

This worked for me in Ubuntu Please try below commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then restarts apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this commands helps!

Comment: For anyone reading my comment, don't forget to restart apache

Comment: Could your maybe add in the answer that it is deprecated in 7.1.x and will be removed in 7.2.x? Source: http://php.net/manual/de/migration71.deprecated.php

Comment: @Ankit Sompura please tell the solution for windows