# installing Mcrypt php extension fails on Ubuntu and Xampp

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, mcrypt

I installed Xampp on Ubuntu 16 to work with Laravel.
I ran my Laravel code and got this error : `Mcrypt PHP extension required.`
After that I tried to install Mcrypt on PHP.

I have done these :

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

I have also done this : [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql)

I also restart the all services from Xampp after every change but I still get error on Laravel.

Any idea ?

My PHP version is 7.0.22 and Ubuntu version is 16.04.1 .

Thank you  .

**Edit 1**

I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402000/php-7-mcrypt-php-extension-required) and I still see the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php 7 Mcrypt PHP extension required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402000/php-7-mcrypt-php-extension-required)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte - it's the same problem but the answer can't solve it .

Answer (score 0):

After trying to many things. I just got rid of this shit by installing both version on my computer.

> First I installed php 7.1.19 version.
>   Secondly I installed php 7.2.15 version

Now I am working perfectly with my project.