# How to replace replace mcrypt_encrypt?

Tags: php, web, encryption

With PHP 7 my website does not work anymore correctly. I tried the recommendation on the website: https://gist.github.com/odan/c1dc2798ef9cedb9fedd09cdfe6e8e76, but it still does not work. Can anyone help me?

error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt() in /is/htdocs/wp12891720_A49KPJUSEX/www/chat.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /is/htdocs/wp12891720_A49KPJUSEX/www/chat.php(131): Crypt::encode('5c46ea88788a0aa...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /is/htdocs/wp12891720_A49KPJUSEX/www/chat.php on line 115

```
class Crypt {
    static public function encode($key, $password) {
        $key .= date('Y-m-d H');
        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), json_encode($password), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this monstrosity supposed to do? Please do not tell me this is a part of some kind of authentication system.

Comment: `open_ssl` is typically what you want to use, you can also use PHPSecLib which is a pretty nice library.

Comment: 1. Passwords need to be _hashed_, not encrypted. 2. Why are you appending the current hour to the key? 3. Why are you `json_encode()`ing the password? 4. IVs should be random, not derived. Last, but not least, mcrypt's Rjindael cipher isn't compatible with any other library, you need to re-encode everything. Take the opportunity to hash your passwords instead. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: That code gave me nightmares...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php 7 Mcrypt PHP extension required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402000/php-7-mcrypt-php-extension-required)

Answer (score 0):

Because, This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Check on official website [PHP: mcrypt_encrypt - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php). In my openion you can replace this with [openssl_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) method