# How can I add php extension mcrypt to Laravel/Homestead?

Tags: php, homestead

I have set up `laravel/homestead`, now when I use composer install on a project, I get the error message:

```
The requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system
```

(I know I shouldn't use mcrypt anymore, but the project was handed over to me so I cant change this for now)

I m using PHP 7.1 (where mcrypt is marked deprecated I think but still usable if I activate it?)

`php -v` shows "7.1.30"

I added `extension=php_mcrypt.dll` into my `php.ini` and then restarted homestead (halt & up again) I can see the line in the `php.ini` now but `php -m` does not show mcrypt... and composer install still fails.

How can I activate mcrypt in homestead?

Comment: There may be more than 1 php.ini, one for CLI and one for web. Make sure you're updating the right one. Also, if you're using Homestead, then you're probably using a Vagrant box that's running Ubuntu, so DLL files would not be valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php 7 Mcrypt PHP extension required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402000/php-7-mcrypt-php-extension-required)

Comment: @DiogoSanto he said he added `extension=php_mcrypt.dll` to `php.ini` and you're talking about unix? @aynber MCrypt was removed from PHP7 for one of the main reasons why you want to upgrade PHP: Security. The MCrypt library is not maintained anymore. There is no way to fix it, it's simply not there anymore. You need to change the code or downgrade (not recommended!!!).

Comment: I'd recommend doing `composer require phpseclib/mcrypt_compat`. That'll install a pure-PHP mcrypt shim that'll eliminate the need for the mcrypt extension.

Comment: phpenmod encrypt gives me: WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available ... (do I have to instal the extension somehow? Or is it already inside Homestead and only needs to be activated?)

Comment: @FlashThunder you are completely right! I removed it now.

Answer (score -1):

`MCrypt` was removed from `PHP7` for one of the main reasons why you want to upgrade PHP: Security. The `MCrypt` library is not maintained anymore. There is no way to fix it on Windows, it's simply not there anymore. You need to change the code or downgrade (not recommended!!!).

Comment: Would be cool, but as I wrote, right now I have no choice because its a legacy project that was just given to me, I need to set it up locally first then I can think about taking the project and changing this